# What Will Happen Without Decimal Expansion?

Tags: irrational-numbers, education, rational-numbers, decimal-expansion

After a discussion on the complexity of decimal expansion (such as $0.\bar{9}=1$), some of my students (middle school) decided to throw away the decimal expansion of some numbers! Namely, the numbers which their decimal expansion is not terminating.

I understand that their decision leads to some problems: We know that decimal expansions of many fractions are not terminating, and no irrational number can be represented as a terminating decimal expansion.

But what are the real **disasters** which occur if we limit the decimal expansions to the numbers with terminating ones? I look for answers which can be comprehended by students in middle school.

Thanks.

Comment: No disasters at all, decimal expansions aren't the only way to express numbers. I'm not sure I understand this question.

Comment: What does it mean to "throw away decimal expansions"? If it's "pretending they don't exist", it's the same thing as when you pretend anything true is false: you're simply wrong.

Comment: @ChristophPegel Decimal expansion is not the only way to express numbers, but if you point a random number on the real line, you won't be sure to be able to represent the corresponding number except using decimal expansion.

Comment: @nik How can one - as a teacher - show the wrongness of their choice? This is what I'm looking for. Something convingcing... .

Comment: Ask'm to write down one third... What is more concrete than one third?

Comment: @Behzad, I could also represent any number by nested intervals of rationals. There are numerous ways of expressing numbers

Comment: @Did They came to the belief that $\dfrac{1}{3}\neq 0.\bar{3}$!

Comment: For all practical purposes, truncating at the $100$-th significant digit would make no difference. But if the *concept* of arbitrary real were missing, a crucial part of the conceptual framework for science would be gone.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Well, how would you explain it to a middle school student?

Comment: I have no experience with Middle School students, apart from "contest kids." Explain that $\frac{1}{3}$ is easier to visualize than $0.3333333$?

Comment: @AndréNicolas In my previous comment, by 'it' I meant the 'crucial part of the conceptual framework for science' which would be gone. How do you explain 'it'?

Comment: My guess is that one should not attempt to, if they have a good visual understanding of the "number line," that is plenty good enough.

Comment: I feel like you would be better asking this question on matheducators.

Answer (score 0):

If you restrict to finite decimal expansions, then every number lives in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[1/10]$. I'm not sure it's a disaster, but it's definitely not the real numbers...

Answer (score 0):

Well, depends what the meaning of "disaster" is.

In the rationals, $ \mathbb Q$, every non-zero quantity is invertible.  Any fraction can be expressed as a finite or infinite repeating decimal.  Thus $1.5$ has as inverse $0.(6)$.  In a more theoretical POV, any linear transformation with coefficients in $ \mathbb Q$ acting on elements of $ \mathbb Q$ will yield results in $ \mathbb Q$, and if invertible, the inverse will have the same property.

However, if you give up infinite repeating decimals not all numbers will have inverses, in a relatively goofy manner.  E.g., $0.5$ will have an inverse, $1.5$ won't, and $2.5$ will again have one, then no $x.5$ will have inverses until $12.5$ etc, etc, etc.  Actually numbers of the type $2^k5^m$, where $k, m$ integer will have finite decimal inverses, none others will.  However in base $12$ only numbers of the type $2^k3^m$, where $k, m$ integer will have finite decimal inverses while in base p (p - prime) only numbers of the type $p^k$, where $k$ integer will have finite decimal inverses.

So not only you lose invertibility of all nonzero quantities, what quantities are invertible becomes dependent on the basis in which you express your rational quantities.  More theoretical, you lose the general invertibility of linear transformations formulated in the universe (set, class) of rational quantities.

---

OTOH, care with infinite expansions will help your students avoid confusing irrational numbers with their infinite decimal expansions, a topic of acerbic controversy between professional mathematicians.

Comment: OTOH, if you mean abandoning the entirety of the decimal expansion, you are talking about the error of rounding to the (nearest) integer. In this case the error increases with the number of elements in the product.  A teaching example could be multiplying 1.5 with itself one, two three, four,.. ten times and comparing to the exact computation.

Answer (score 0):

Hint.-I would do it this way:

You can start with a lesson about countable and uncountable sets.

Rinse thoroughly that $\mathbb Q $ is countable and $\mathbb R$ is uncountable.

Then tell them the numbers with finite decimal expansion form a "very small"   subset of $\mathbb Q$.

Play with that "very small" (it is infinite and equals $\mathbb Z[\frac {1}{10}]$).

End with the most of the real numbers
left out of consideration when you see just finite decimal expansion.